# XSLT - nested loop

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble with an XSLT to loop through all the rows, and then all the columns in each row element.

So if this is the XML I have:

```
<root>
<subelement>
<rows>
<row title="Row1">
  <column title="A" />
  <column title="B" />
</row>
<row title="Row2">
  <column title="C" />
  <column title="D" />
</row>
</rows>
</subelement>
</root>
```

I would like output like this:

```
<h1>Row1</h1>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
<h1>Row2</h1>
<ul>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Regards

Peter

Comment: You want something. SO is about asking questions. Also most people don't like to provide full solutions without the asker being proactive and providing a specific problem.

Comment: This looks pretty simple to me,  what, exactly, is the trouble you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="row">
     <h1><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></h1>
     <ul>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="column">
   <li><xsl:value-of select="@title"/></li>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <subelement>
        <rows>
            <row title="Row1">
                <column title="A" />
                <column title="B" />
            </row>
            <row title="Row2">
                <column title="C" />
                <column title="D" />
            </row>
        </rows>
    </subelement>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted output:**

```
<h1>Row1</h1>
<ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
</ul>
<h1>Row2</h1>
<ul>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a book I can recommend to learn XSLT:

XSLT: Programmer's Reference, 2nd Edition, Michael Kay

Also, this website is very handy, it even has an online XSLT tester: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp